# A single "Navigation Drawer Activity" in Android Studio for multiple classes and activities

Tags: java, android, navigation

I need a single "Navigation Drawer Activity" in Android Studio for multiple classes and activities, I tried to learn this myself but I don't get the result I want. I need all new classes making extrens to baseActivity to be able to call the side menu. Right now there is no such feature, and whatever I do I can't get it to work. Here is my code for understanding:
**BaseActivity**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
public ActivityBaseBinding binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityBaseBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId(); // загружаем в ид какую кнопку нажал пользователь
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}

**DrawerLayout**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_base"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_base"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_base_drawer"
    />
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: It may not help your situation much, but come over to the modern Android architecture/techstack:  kotlin, coroutines, hilt and compose

Comment: @KristyWelsh Can you tell me which method would work best for my need? I need a side menu

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/navigation-drawer-in-android/

Comment: @KristyWelsh
That doesn't solve my goal, unfortunately. The goal is for this menu to be available from all classes and activites.

Comment: Using multiple activities for a navigation drawer hasn't been a recommended practice for [over 4 years](https://youtu.be/2k8x8V77CrU).